# i want to add a site to my url string without editing the code

Tags: python, cookies

sorry for the bad title as i am currently rushing since this is a assignment provided to me.
I am making a Program that can extract cookies say if you forgot a login etc, but i have a string at the beginning of my code ' URL = 'https://google.com' and that gives me my cookies from google! But i don't want to manually edit the code and put in a site every time i wanna check my cookies.

```
import urllib, http.cookiejar
  URL = 'https://google.com'

  def extract_cookies():
    cookie_jar = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()

    url_opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar))
    url_opener.open(URL)
    for cookie in cookie_jar:
      print("COOKIE NAME: %s COOKIE_VALUE = %s" %(cookie.name, cookie.value))

  if __name__ == '__main__': 
    extract_cookies()
```

at first i tried using the string 'URL' as a input function but i got myself in a knot so i came here to ask instead for any advice and examples, any help would be greatly appreciated! this is the forked part that i am adding on too every few hours, so it may seem very small and weird this is just a small base haha.

Comment: well You have to somehow input all of the websites You want to check anyways. You can do either `input()` at the beginning of the program and ask for URL or make a list and type an integer for input instead which will index the url list

Comment: Yeah, i was thinking a way to make this a
"enter site URL: " thing or something as that will keep it more simple, but i will try that! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so this is one way to do this (still have to write out those urls):

```
my_urls = ['google.com', 'yahoo.com', 'youtube.com']

for index, name in enumerate(my_urls):
    print(index, name)
url = my_urls[int(input(f'Choose an integer for url: '))]

print(url)
```